# how to pass two parameter and get the filtered result in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have made table in MYSQL with columns  'name','worker_id','local_job_id' here my php code gives the corresponding name for the given local_job_id 
from the link

```
http://allwaysready.16mb.com/Cuboid/LocalCheckRequest.php?local_job_id[]=3
```

Gives

```
{"result":[{"worker_id":"2"},{"worker_id":"1"}]}
```

but what i want to change in this code is display the name if both worker_id AND local_job_id are matching .

"http://allwaysready.16mb.com/Cuboid/LocalCheckRequest.php?local_job_id[]=3=2&worker_id=2" then the 'name' which corresponding to the local_job_id=3 and worker_id=2 should be displayed.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $local_job_id = $_GET['local_job_id'];
    require_once ('dbConnect.php');

    $local_job_request = array();
    foreach($_REQUEST['local_job_id'] as $key => $val) {
        $local_job_request[$key] = filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }

    $local_job_ids = "'" . implode("','", $local_job_request) . "'";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM local_job_request WHERE local_job_id IN ({$local_job_ids})";
    $r = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $result = array();
    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        array_push($result, array(
            "worker_id" => $res['worker_id']
        ));
    }

    echo json_encode(array(
        "result" => $result
    ));
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Well why dont you have a go at doing that SO != **Get your coding done free here**

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this might be helpful for you

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

    $local_job_id  = $_REQUEST['local_job_id'];
    $worker_id  = $_GET['worker_id'];
    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $local_job_request = array();

           foreach ($local_job_id as $key => $val) {
           $local_job_request[$key] = filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            }
            $local_job_ids = "'" . implode("','", $local_job_request) . "'";

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM local_job_request WHERE local_job_id IN ({$local_job_ids})";

            if(isset($worker_id) && $worker_id != "") {
                $sql .= " AND worker_id = ".$worker_id;
            }
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $result = array();

            while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

    array_push($result,array(
        "worker_id"=>$res['worker_id']
        )
    );
            }
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);

}
```

Comment: url will be the same but you have to check for extra parameter

Comment: i used this URL: "http://allwaysready.16mb.com/Cuboid/LocalCheckRequest.php?local_job_id[]=3&worker_id[]=2" but i get the error:" unexpected end of file"

Comment: can you provide screen shot ?